# how does Postgres support async(non-block) operator in term of socket protocol?

Tags: postgresql, asynchronous, network-protocols

I'm not find any document to clarify how does Postgres handle request-response for async non-block request at the socket protocol level.

As a example, suggest only two query-sql in pg-client which use one socket connection to pg-server. I'm suppose there are two way to handle asyc operation:

1. client can't send second command before the first request not response.

```
client   socket1       server
   -----query1---------->
   <----response1--------
   ------query2--------->
   <-----response1-------
```

2. socket send two querys at sametime and distinct response by a unique flag.

```
client       socket1          server
   -------query1 + uid:msg1----->
   -------query2 + uid:msg2----->
   <------response2 + uid:msg2---
   <------response1 + uid:msg1---
```

I think it should be the second way to handle request as real async process but I'm not find any resource from [document](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol.html).
Question:

1. which one is the Postgres handle async socket operation?
2. If use the first way and why?

Comment: I didn't think Postgres supports asynchronous requests - without using multiple connections at least

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the network protocol level, there is no distinction between synchronous and asynchronous mode. The difference is only in the way the client API works.

There is always at most one statement active at any given time. See for example [the documentation for the simple protocol](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/protocol-flow.html#id-1.10.5.7.4), but it is the same for the extended protocol.

The difference is in the way the client API works:

- In synchronous mode, the client thread is blocked until the query result us complete.
- In asynchronous mode, control is returned to the client thread immediately after sending the query, and the client can go and do something else while it waits for the server response. It has to poll the socket regularly to check if the result has arrived. Then it can read and process the result.

If you want to run two statements concurrently, you have to use two database sessions.

Comment: Hi, In a word, postgres's session is a socket connection and a session can't do multiple query at sametime.Client Application should be create multiple socket session for concurrent. Why Postgres not use the seconed way to support concurrent sql command in one session?

Comment: "Why" questions are hard to answer with certainty. The obvious reason is that it would be much harder to implement. Then you'd need an entirely new protocol, because it is no longer clear which response is for which request. And since there is the easy workaround of opening several database connections, why bother?